# Setting Crypto Library to UTF8 with NodeJS Pipe

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pipeline, cryptojs

I get a stream of data with a query over `PostgreSQL`, then I encrypt this data in `JSON` format with the help of cipher and send it directly to the user (chunk type). The problem here is that while cipher encodes, it does not encode the data as `utf8`. I am working as in the code below.

`pg-query-stream` library is used.

`updateProvider` connects to the pool method in the `pg` library.

```
updateProvider.connect(async (err, client, done) => {
           if (err) throw err
           const query = new QueryStream('SELECT * FROM table')
           const stream = await client.query(query)
           stream.on('end', done)
           stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(cipher).pipe(res)
       })
```

My cipher usage is as follows:

```
const cipher = await crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from('y642GnzY61Has9hoKPAQereA3Jih3XiW'), Buffer.from('usLmN9ZtJn1D0ArF'));
```

In this code, I want to encode the cipher with utf8 during the pipe or before. My only condition is not to lose big in terms of performance. I found solutions with the for loop, but I did not take it as a realistic solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did some work on generating alternative routes and I searched if I could do this on the client side so as not to increase the load during the pipe on the server side, and found a workable solution. I wanted to share this with you.

First of all, the following site gave me an idea;

https://mothereff.in/utf-8

[image]

Afterwards, I reached the NodeJS package below and looked for a way to code from their code on the client side.

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js

Since the client application was developed with Delphi, I made the following change on the Delphi side and I got the solution. The solution I made was `UTF8ToString` definition. `UTF8Encode` etc. functions did not provide a solution.

```
UTF8ToString(decryptionStream.DataString)
```

I hope it helps, if a different solution comes up, I will enjoy applying it.

Thanks.